# chrome.windows.create

Tags: javascript, extensión-google-chrome

Intento que desde un addon cree una nueva ventana al estilo popup, pero la documentación de Google parece insuficiente.

Código:

```
var opciones ={
    'url': url, 
    'width':400, 
    'height':300,
    'type': 'popup'
};

chrome.windows.create(opciones, function(window) {
    console.log("ventana creada");
});
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, me dice:

> ```
>  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
> ```

La verdad no sé donde podría estar el fallo.

Comment: A mí me funciona sin problemas: se abre la ventana y en el log veo "Ventana creada". ¿Cómo lo estás probando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que estés tratando de realizar la llamada a la API desde un [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). Éstos no pueden acceder a la mayor parte de funcionalidades de las APIs de Google, solo a las listadas en la [documentación](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Una posible solución es delegar la llamada a un background script, enviándole un [mensaje](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), y que sea éste el que ejecute la acción.